# webpack with bootstrap.css not work

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, webpack, webpack-2, webpack-style-loader

This is my *webpack.config.js* file:

```
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin'),
    webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    entry: [
        './src/app.js',
    ],
    output: {
        path: __dirname + '/../web/js',
        filename: 'build.js',
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: 'babel-loader'
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style-loader', 'css-loader')
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)$/,
                loader: "url?limit=5000"
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            $: "jquery",
            jQuery: "jquery"
        }),
        new ExtractTextPlugin('build.css')
    ]
}
```

This is my *package.json* file:

```
"dependencies": {
    "angular": "^1.6.4",
    "babel-core": "^6.25.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.1",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.4",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0",
    "file-loader": "^0.11.2",
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    "style-loader": "^0.18.2",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.9",
    "webpack": "^3.4.1"
}
```

This is my *app.js* file:

```
import 'babel-polyfill';
import $ from 'jquery';
import 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
```

After trying to start the webpack I get an error.

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css Module parse failed:
/var/www/dcracks/app/webpack/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css
Unexpected token (7:5) You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
  |  */
  | /*! normalize.css v3.0.3
  | MIT License
  | github.com/necolas/normalize.css */
  | html {
  |   font-family: sans-serif;
  |   -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  @ ./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css 4:14-42
  @ ./src/app.js  @ multi ./src/app.js
```

I reread already a bunch of material and shoveled a bunch of posts in various forums.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [signature of `ExtractTextPlugin.extract`](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/extract-text-webpack-plugin#extract) is:

```
ExtractTextPlugin.extract(options: loader | object)
```

As there is no second argument, your `css-loader` is not being used. The most common configuration is to use `css-loader` to process the CSS files and `style-loader` as a fallback, which is used when it shouldn't be extracted (the configured loaders are still applied, but instead of being extracted the fallback loader is used).

You can use the rule that is shown in the [Readme - Usage](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/extract-text-webpack-plugin#usage).

```
{
  test: /\.css$/,
  use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
    fallback: 'style-loader',
    use: 'css-loader'
  })
}
```